# How can I see vertex behind weight paint?

Tags: weight-painting

In 2.79 in weight paint mode, when you chose wireframe mode you were able to see the weight color in front and see through the color to reveal the vertex behind the shape.

In 2.8 weight paint transparency fades the weight paint but still not transparent.

Very useful when using selected vertex for weight painting.

Is there a way in 2.8?